# .htaccess redirect to page based on domain name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make a redirection based on the domain name of my website.

I have two urls:

- domain-english.com
- domain-french.com

The default language is english so when users type domain-english.com no redirection is needed.
But when users type in domain-french.com, I would like it to go directly to domain-french.com/fr

In my htaccess file I tried different solutions I found on Google.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-french.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-french.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-french.com/fr [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php 


</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This does redirect to the url domain-french.com/fr but I get this error

> The page isn't redirecting properly

**EDIT** 
I also tried this configuration in my .htaccess file but I get a 500 Server Error.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-french.com
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-french.com/fr [L]
```

Any ideas what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just contacted my hosting provider, they said that it is prohibited on their server thus explaining why it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for the help! –

Answer (score 2):

Change your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-french\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(?!fr/).*$ fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it, but I still get the 500 Server Error.

Comment: Can you pls check error.log and tell me what is the the actual error.

Comment: Just contacted my hosting provider, they said that it is prohibited on their server thus explaining why it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: Oh if .htaccess is prohibited then I guess you it needs to be enabled by them. Any new application installation like Wordpress, Magento, Joomla etc need .htaccess manipulation.

Comment: htaccess is allowed but the consider both-domains being two different sites if if one is a parked domain of the other.